# ¿como puedo hacer un trigger u otra función que me permita eliminar todos los datos de una tabla antes de hacer las inserciones en la misma tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, trigger

```
create trigger fifidelete 
BEFORE INSERT ON temp
.......
delete from temp
....
end
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual seria el problema con esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al crear un trigger que elimine los datos de una tabla antes de insertar un nuevo registro ocurriría lo siguiente. En la tabla siempre existiría un único registro puesto que, el trigger se acciona por cada uno de los registros que ocurran sobre la tabla y por ende cada que vez que se registre uno nuevo se elimina el anterior.

En ese caso se debe realizar un trigger que se accione antes de que se realice el registro, para que elimine el registro anterior de la tabla:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_fifidelete BEFORE INSERT ON nombreTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

---PARA ELIMINAR LOS REGISTROS DE UNA TABLA PUEDES USAR YA SEA TRUNCATE O DELETE CONSIDERANDO LO SIGUIENTE.

---DELETE SE PUEDE EJECUTAR AUNQUE LA TABLA SE RELACIONE CON OTRAS SIEMPRE Y CUANDO NO EXISTAN REGISTROS ASOCIADOS. PARA ELLO PRIMERO SE ELIMINAN LOS REGISTROS ASOCIADOS Y DESPUES SE PUEDE VACIAR LA TABLA.

DELETE FROM nombreTabla; 

---TRUNCATE NO SE PUEDE EJECUTAR SI LA TABLA SE RELACIONA CON OTRAS TABLAS AUNQUE NO HAYA REGISTROS, SE PUEDE SOLUCIONAR CAMBIANDO LA RESTRICCIÓN DE LLAVES FORANEAS DE LAS TABLAS INVOLUCRADAS POR ON DELETE CASCADE Y ON UPDATE CASCADE. SOLO ASÍ SE PERMITE VACIAR LA TABLA.

TRUNCATE TABLE nombreTabla;

END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Una vez que se haya ejecutado el trigger, se eliminan los registros de las tablas y se registra el nuevo.

Comment: Habra alguna manera para que no se ejecute por cada fila? osea que no se repita el trigger cada que haga un insert si no que se ejecute hasta el ultimo insert? perdón si no me explico

Comment: En ese caso un trigger no funciona para hacer lo que quieres puesto que, un trigger se ejecuta automáticamente por cada evento ocurrido sobre una tabla de la base de datos. Si quieres registrar datos y solo eliminarlos cuando tu lo decidas, puedes hacerlo con un procedimiento almacenado, pero tendrías que mandarle una bandera que indique si solo quieres registrar o bien eliminar todos antes de insertar uno nuevo. Aunque esto te lo puedes evitar del lado de base de datos y mejor hacerlo desde el lado de tu programa validando cuando debes vaciar la tabla.

Comment: ya veo, pues muchas gracias, seguire tu consejo y validare esa parte desde el programa :D